# Dual basis with non-degenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional vector space and $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ a basis. Let $\beta:V\times V\rightarrow F$ be a non-degenerate (symmetric) bilinear form. This implies that there exists a dual basis $\{y_1,\cdots, y_n\}$ of $V$ w.r.t. $\beta$, i.e. 
$$\beta(x_i,y_j)=\delta_{ij}.$$
Can we write expression for basis elements $y_i$'s in terms of $x_i$'s and matrix of $\beta$ w.r.t. basis $\{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$?

---

This is an obvious computational question and may be very trivial, but I didn't find in any book mentioning about computation of dual basis. For example, as a concrete example, let $V$ be the space of column vectors of length $n$ over field $\mathbb{R}$. Consider dot product on this column space.  Then given any invertible $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$, its $n$ columns define a basis of $V$; what is dual basis w.r.t. dot product? Perhaps it is columns of $(A^{-1})^t$, am I right? Then next question comes more general, which I put above.

Comment: Suppose that you do have such a dual basis already: then each of the y's can be written as a linear combination of the x's. Use that and the condition that you have a dual basis to write down linear equations on the coefficients which you can then solve. This is just the same thing one does to find the basis of the dual space of V which is dual to a given basis of V.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\beta : V \times V \to F$ is given, we know that the value of $\beta$ is known for any given input $(v,w) \in V \times V$. So in principle the matrix $[\beta(x_i,x_j)]$ is determined.

Let $y_i = \sum_{k} A_{ik}x_k$, we have
$$
\delta_{ij} = \beta(x_i,y_j) = \beta \Big(x_i,\sum_{k}A_{jk} x_k\Big) =\sum_{k} A_{jk} \beta(x_i,x_k) = \sum_{k}A_{jk}\beta_{ik} =\sum_k A_{jk}\beta_{ki}.
$$
This read in matrix notation as
$$[A_{ik}][\beta_{kj}] = I \implies [A_{ij}]=[\beta_{ij}]^{-1} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the matrix with entries $b_{i,j}=\beta(x_i,x_j)$. It's symmetric
and invertible. Write $C=B^{-1}=(c_{i,j})$. Then $y_j=\sum_kc_{j,k}x_k$.
One checks
$$\beta(x_i,y_j)=\sum_k c_{j,k}b_{i,k}=\delta_{i,j}$$
using the fact that $CB^t=CB=I$.